# regex ignore capturing group inside capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture a group but at the same time ignore a sub group but need the subgroup to be true to capture it. For example:

```
/^(?:\s*)([abc])?(?:\s*)((?:d){1}[ef]*)(.*)/.exec(' a deee ghi')
// is equal to                [" a deee ghi", "a", "deee", " ghi"]
// but I really want equal to [" a deee ghi", "a", "eee", " ghi"]

// and I want this to fail:
/^(?:\s*)([abc])?(?:\s*)((?:d){1}[ef]*)(.*)/.exec(' a eee ghi')
//                            [" a eee ghi", "a", "", "eee ghi"]
```

I'm trying to ignore the `'d'` in the capturing group but only want it captured if there's a `'d'` before any `'e'`s of `'f'`s in the third group

How would I do this?

EDIT:

To clairify, I want the third group to be filled only if there's a `'d'` in the string there. else -> don't capture the `'e'`s or `'f'`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: if the `d` is there, then the capture-group should be `eee`, but if the `d` is not there, then the capture-group should be blank or null. Is that correct? If so, you can write:

```
/^(?:\s*)([abc])?(?:\s*)(?:d([ef]*)|[ef]*)(.*)/.exec(' a deee ghi')
```

to match `([ef]*)` when `d` is present, and `[ef]*` when it is not.